# dm-crypt and LUKS password rotation

Tags: security, users, encryption, key-authentication

How do you protect the master key, and distribute multiple passwords for admin access? Is there a 3rd party user management tool or is this native?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot protect the master key, as everyone who has root access or the password to one key slot can extract it easily by running

```
dmsetup table --target crypt --showkey /dev/mapper/YourDevice
```